# Selenium: WebDriverException:Chrome failed to start: crashed as google-chrome is no longer running so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Recently I switched computers and since then I can't launch chrome with selenium. I've also tried Firefox but the browser instance just doesn't launch.

```
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.Chrome('/home/PycharmProjects/chromedriver')

d.get('https://www.google.nl/')
```

I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600233, platform=Linux 4.15.0-38-generic x86_64)
```

I have the latest chrome version and chromedriver installed.

EDIT:
After trying @b0sss solution I am getting the following error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome is no longer running, so chromedriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600233 (523efee95e3d68b8719b3a1c83051aa63aa6b10d),platform=Linux 4.15.0-38-generic x86_64)
```

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Try to download HERE and use this latest chrome driver version:

- https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
d = webdriver.Chrome('/home/<user>/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
d.get('https://www.google.nl/')
```

Comment: I have already downloaded the latest chromedriver from that location.

Comment: @SOeh try the Edited solution

Comment: I think this ans is for docker env.

Comment: I tried that method by adding the 3 arguments and seems to be working fine

Comment: Make sure that `--no-sandbox` option is the first one (unlike this example, where the first option is `--headless`. I kept getting that error, until I moved the `--no-sandbox` to the top of the list, adding it as the first option.

Comment: Note: `from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options`

Comment: as far as I know `--no-sandbox` chrome options argument is enough

Comment: you need to match the versions of chromedriver which 
you use with chromium

Comment: Also running the chrome with non-root user is very important for chromedriver to spawn chrome process successfully.

Comment: Adding just `--headless` as an option to the chromedriver worked for me

Answer (score 41):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *WebBrowser* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the *Chrome* browser is not installed at the **default location** within your system.

The server i.e. *ChromeDriver* expects you to have *Chrome* installed in the *default location* for each system as per the image below:

[image: Chrome_binary_expected_location]

<sup>1</sup>For Linux systems, the ChromeDriver expects `/usr/bin/google-chrome` to be a symlink to the actual Chrome binary.

---

### Solution

In case you are using a *Chrome* executable in a non-standard location you have to *override the Chrome binary location* as follows:

- *Python* Solution:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.binary_location = "C:\\path\\to\\chrome.exe"    #chrome binary location specified here
  options.add_argument("--start-maximized") #open Browser in maximized mode
  options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") #bypass OS security model
  options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage") #overcome limited resource problems
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('http://google.com/')
  ```
- *Java* Solution:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
  opt.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");  //chrome binary location specified here
  options.addArguments("start-maximized");
  options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
  options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
  ```

Comment: Setting the chrome binary worked. Gave you best answer. Also completely deleting Chrome/Chromedriver/Pycharm and then reinstalling everything did the trick as well, so now I won't have the set chrome binary.

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: was killed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

I am getting this(`killed`) instead of `crashed` now. I have been looking up on the web fro 3+ hours now and nothing seems to be working

Answer (score 20):

hope this helps someone. this worked for me on Ubuntu 18.10

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
print('test')
driver.close()
```

Comment: Works on raspberry pi 3b+ (os lite) with chromium.

Comment: Works, with downloaded driver and driver manager. Though, using the service object fails.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue, and discovered that **option arguments must be in a certain order**. I am only aware of the two arguments that were required to get this working on my Ubuntu 18 machine. This sample code worked on my end:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

d = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/home/PycharmProjects/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
d.get('https://www.google.nl/')
```

Comment: isnt, using --no--sandbox option a security issue?

Answer (score 8):

I encountered the exact problem running on docker container (in build environment). After ssh into the container, I tried running the test manually and still encountered

```
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
     (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable is 
      no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

When I tried running chrome locally `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable`, error message

```
Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported
```

I checked my ChromeOptions and it was missing `--no-sandbox`, which is why it couldn't spawn chrome.

```
capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
  chromeOptions: { args: %w(headless --no-sandbox disable-gpu window-size=1920,1080) }
)
```

Comment: Another way to fix this is to not run the process (within the container) as root. This is better from a security perspective, anyway. :)

Answer (score 7):

For RobotFramework

I solved it! using `--no-sandbox`

```
${chrome_options}=  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    test-type
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-extensions
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --headless
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-gpu
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --no-sandbox
Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome_options}
```

Instead of

```
Open Browser    about:blank    headlesschrome
Open Browser    about:blank    chrome
```

Comment: i am also facing the same problem but was a little confused regarding your above comment. can you please help. my current code is SeleniumLibrary.Open Browser  about:blank  ${BROWSER}  ..so i replace this line with your statements?

Comment: robotframework-seleniumlimbrary: `Open Browser    ${url}    ${browser}    options=add_argument("--no-sandbox")`

Answer (score 5):

in my case, the error was with www-data user but not with normal user on development. The error was a problem to initialize an x display for this user. So, the problem was resolved running my selenium test without opening a browser window, headless:

```
opts.set_headless(True)
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution that no one else has said but worked for me was not running without `sudo` or not as root.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you already downloaded chromeDriver, this error is also occurs when already multiple chrome tabs are open.

If you close all tabs and run again, the error should clear up.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions that every body provide here is good for Clear the face of the issue but

All you need to solve this problem is that You have to run The App on **non-root** user
on linux.

> According to this post

**https://github.com/paralelo14/google_explorer/issues/2#issuecomment-246476321**

Answer (score 2):

Just do not run the script as the **root** user (in my case).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but it was solved just by reinstalling chrome again with the commands below:

```
$ wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

This error has been happening randomly during my test runs over the last six months (still happens with Chrome 76 and Chromedriver 76) and only on Linux. On average one of every few hundred tests would fail, then the next test would run fine.

Unable to resolve the issue, in Python I wrapped the `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` in a try..except block in setUp() in my test case class that all my tests are derived from. If it hits the Webdriver exception it waits ten seconds and tries again.

It solved the issue I was having; not elegantly but it works.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

try:
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
except WebDriverException as e:
    print("\nChrome crashed on launch:")
    print(e)
    print("Trying again in 10 seconds..")
    sleep(10)
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
    print("Success!\n")
except Exception as e:
    raise Exception(e)
```

Comment: I see this error with `selenium==4.0.0.b1` `selenium==4.0.0.a7` works fine, only in linux, windows fine.

Comment: `capabilities` is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that both the `chromedriver` and `google-chrome` executable have execute permissions

```
sudo chmod -x "/usr/bin/chromedriver"

sudo chmod -x "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
```

Comment: sudo chmod +x "/usr/bin/chromedriver"

sudo chmod +x "/usr/bin/google-chrome"

Answer (score 1):

I came across this error on linux environment. If not using headless then you will need

```
from sys import platform
    if platform != 'win32':
        from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
        display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
        display.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Faced with this issue trying to run/debug Python Selenium script inside WSL2 using Pycharm debugger.
First solution was to use `--headless` mode, but I prefer to have Chrome GUI during the debug process.

In the system terminal outside Pycharm debugger Chrome GUI worked nice with `DISPLAY` env variable set this way (followed guide [here](https://www.gregbrisebois.com/posts/chromedriver-in-wsl2/)):

`export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2; exit;}'):0.0`

Unfortunately `~/.bashrc` is not running in Pycharm during the debug, export is not working.

The way I've got Chrome GUI worked from Pycharm debugger: run `echo $DISPLAY` in WSL2, paste ip (you've got something similar to this) `172.18.144.1:0` into Pycharm Debug Configuration > Environment Variables:

[image]

Comment: Found similar solution in the clone question, this also may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/57403093/6875391

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it buy killing all the chrome processeses running in the remote server before running my script.
That may explain why some answers that recommend you run your script as root works.

```
$ pkill -9 chrome
$ ./my_script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem. I was run it on terminal with "sudo geany", you should run it without "sudo" just type on terminal "geany" and it is solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem but i solved it by moving the chromedriver to this path
'/opt/google/chrome/'

and this code works correctly

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
driver = Chrome('/opt/google/chrome/chromedrive')
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, chrome was broken. following two lines fixed the issue,

```
apt -y update; apt -y upgrade; apt -y dist-upgrade
apt --fix-broken install
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when you where developing in local, you used options.headless=False in order to see what is the browser doing but you forgot to change it to True in the vm.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32371328)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the root issue was that the google-chrome/chromedriver version were not compatible with the Selenium version.

Seleniumn and Chrome were working fine until a few days ago and I started getting this missing DevToolsActivePort issue. After trying all sorts of solutions on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60081937/webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-crashed-erro), it finally occurred to me that the Chrome version might not be compatible with the Selenium version.
Versions at the time of the initial error:

```
# Below combo does NOT work
Python 3.7.3
selenium==3.141.0
Google Chrome 110.0.5481.77
ChromeDriver 110.0.5481.77
```

I then downgraded Chrome and ChromeDriver to 109.0.5414.74 but still faced the same error. I checked the versions on a different machine and saw that this combo worked:

```
# Below combo works
Python 3.7.6
selenium==3.141.0
Google Chrome 80.0.3987.100
ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.16
```

However, I wasn't able to find a download for Google Chrome V80. This [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/690069) had a download to V97 so that's the version I went with. There might be higher versions of Google Chrome that do work but after spending so many days fixing this, I was eager to move onto something else.

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
sudo wget http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_97.0.4692.71-1_amd64.deb && \
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_97.0.4692.71-1_amd64.deb && \
sudo apt-mark hold google-chrome-stable

wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/97.0.4692.71/chromedriver_linux64.zip
sudo unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin
```

After that, my Selenium calls were able to work again. The final version combo:

```
# Below combo works
Python 3.7.3
selenium==3.141.0
ChromeDriver 97.0.4692.71
Google Chrome 97.0.4692.71
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I was running chromedriver from a user that did not have a home directory, and apparently chromium needs one.

So I have used `mkhomedir_helper <username>` to create it and everything worked again.