# Chromedriver doesn't open on windows?

Tags: django, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I have a django application that it uses selenium and chromedriver on ubuntu  when I try to open the application from windows the chromedriver doesn't open

> WebDriverException at /scrap
>
> Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
>     (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
>     (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609551 (5d576e9a44fe4c5b6a07e568f1ebc753f1214634),platform=Linux 4.15.0-1030-azure x86_64)

NB: the django application is installed under ubuntu 18 after using apache2 i could access to the application from windows but the part using chromedriver doesn't work

Comment: You need to be more specific. What exactly are you doing? Are you seeing an error when you run your tests? And check that the chrome driver you installed is compatible with the version of Chrome installed.

Comment: I installed a chromedriver in linux and i am trying to open the django application with windows . is that possible?

Comment: Again, please be more specific, describe the environment, what's installed where, what commands are you running, how is the linux installation related to windows?

Comment: Check this discussion [Selenium: WebDriverException:Chrome failed to start: crashed as google-chrome is no longer running so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073411/selenium-webdriverexceptionchrome-failed-to-start-crashed-as-google-chrome-is)

Comment: I checked it but it doesn't solve my problem