# Why chrome webdriver configuration is invalid?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run a scraper using Selenium driver

My py file is (just start)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

# Set the url we want
<and so on>
```

However I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 37, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_respons
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming  has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628388 (4a34a70827ac54148e092aafb70504c4ea7ae926),platform=Linux 4.4.0-140-generic
```

Searching for this error, it seems as if its incompatibility in ChromeDriver and Google-Chrome and Selenium however my Selenium version is `3.141.0`, my chrome version is `72.0.3626.119` and my ChromeDriver is `2.46`.

So they are all latest and they all seem compatible.

Any ideas what wrong?

Comment: Does this error occur every time? Have you tried to rerun the test a couple of times?

Comment: Yes, tried several times but same error.

Comment: Can you try to run the chromedriver on its own?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53078276/6808714

Comment: did you specify the path of chrome driver

Comment: @MaHrezBenHamad Chrome syslink is already present as it says in that post.

Comment: Try this @Alludy1962:                                                                                
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
return webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

Comment: @Alludy1962: Also if you find  solution for your problem - you still might get that error occasionally.  There is a bug in the chromedriver, and it is not fixed yet https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome/issues/46

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ran into this error on Ubuntu 18.04 and it could be one of several things that's causing Chrome to crash. Try setting these flags:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver", chrome_options=options)
```

The `--headless` flag ensures that Chrome starts in headless mode as I assume you don't have a desktop running on your Ubuntu. the `--no-sandbox` flag turns off the sandboxing in Linux that sometimes causes problems at the start.