# Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally through Jenkins on Ubuntu?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, selenium-chromedriver, jenkins-cli

As I am new to Jenkins where I am trying to trigger a job. Please help me to understand below issue so I can resolve it and make it working.

I am trying to run maven from ubuntu CLI using jenkins. And I am getting below 
error.
Path is set for drivers as below

> {"/usr/bin/geckodriver","/usr/bin/chromedriver"};

Below is console log:

```
14:51:02    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
14:51:02    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
14:51:02    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
14:51:02    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
14:51:02    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
14:51:02    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
14:51:02    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
14:51:02    at classes.Base.setUp(Base.java:71)
14:51:02    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
14:51:02    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
14:51:02    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:51:02    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
14:51:02    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
14:51:02    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
14:51:02    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
14:51:02    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
14:51:02    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:175)
14:51:02    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:107)
14:51:02    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
14:51:02    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
14:51:02    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
14:51:02    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
14:51:02    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
14:51:02    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
14:51:02    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
14:51:02    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
14:51:02    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
14:51:02    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
14:51:02    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
14:51:02    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:77)
14:51:02    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:110)
14:51:02    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:106)
14:51:02    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
14:51:02    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
14:51:02    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:51:02    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
14:51:02    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
14:51:02    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
14:51:02    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
14:51:02    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
14:51:02    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
14:51:02 
14:51:02 
14:51:02 Results :
14:51:02 
14:51:02 Failed tests:   setUp(Testcases.TestCase): unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally(..)
14:51:02
```

Comment: Could you please repaste your stack trace and format it as code to preserve the new lines?

Comment: Please check as I have formatted the logs.

Comment: Please take a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073411/selenium-webdriverexceptionchrome-failed-to-start-crashed-as-google-chrome-is