# Unable to launch chrome browser on mac using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I'm not able to launch chrome browser on mac using selenium.

I have following configurations:

> Mac OS X 10.14.6
>
> Chrome version: 78.0.3904.97
>
> ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70 (downloaded from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)
>
> Python 3

I tried steps mentioned in [this](http://learn-automation.com/chrome-browser-on-mac-using-selenium/) blog to set the chromedriver and using simple browser launch code

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Unfortunately i encountered with following error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
> Chrome failed to start: crashed   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort
> file doesn't exist)   (The process started from chrome location
> /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome is no
> longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Non of these solution working for me

[Selenium: WebDriverException:Chrome failed to start: crashed as google-chrome is no longer running so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073411/selenium-webdriverexceptionchrome-failed-to-start-crashed-as-google-chrome-is)

[image]

Comment: @DebanjanB, nothing working in my case from link which you marked duplicate. also attached then snap of chrome crash report have a look

Comment: @DebanjanB, Any update ? could you remove the duplicate

Comment: There are 3 duplicates of this question. Can you update your question with the steps which you have taken as per the duplicate targets?