# WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/google-chrome unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -11 with ChromeDriver Chrome through Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run webdriver in a Python script, and when the script tries to run google chrome it exits with status code 11.

Here is the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/google-chrome')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get('http://www.google.com/');
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()
```

Here is the full output:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx pythonscrape]$ python3 test-selenium-chrome.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-selenium-chrome.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/google-chrome')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/google-chrome unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -11
```

Does anyone know why my script reports the error code 11 when trying to run google chrome?

Comment: I believe this line: driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/google-chrome')  Should be the path to the chromedriver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/google-chrome unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -11
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn the new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session properly.

Seems you were almost there. The default argument for `webdriver.Chrome()` is the *absolute path* of the *ChromeDriver* binary. However, as per best practices you must send both the *Key* and the *Value* as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path
```

Further, if you need to pass the *absolute path* of the *Chrome* binary you have to use the `binary_location` property through an instance of `chrome.options` as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = '/path/to/chrome'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion in:

- [Selenium: WebDriverException:Chrome failed to start: crashed as google-chrome is no longer running so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073411/selenium-webdriverexceptionchrome-failed-to-start-crashed-as-google-chrome-is/53078276#53078276)