# Selenium with Chromedriver only works with headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, manjaro

I'm trying to run this in Python on Manjaro Linux.

I've written some functional tests which we'd like to see running on our screens in our office. However, the tests only work if I pass a `--headless` option, which we absolutely do not want. Otherwise, the constant error we get is `The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.`. So this error is instantly gone when I pass along the `--headless` argument, which is very frustrating at this point. 
This is the code I'm trying with now:

```
 options = Options()
 options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
 options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
 options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
 options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
 options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
 # options.add_argument("--headless")
 driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver", chrome_options=options)
```

Any tips are highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: which version of the chrome driver you are using? are testing in local or docker?

Comment: Chromedriver is at version 80, as well as Chrome. I'm testing locally.

Comment: I'm also running into this problem. Were you ever able to figure it out, and if so what did you do?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because your chrome is not installed on the default location. A detailed explanation is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073411/selenium-webdriverexceptionchrome-failed-to-start-crashed-as-google-chrome-is). You can specify the location that chrome is running from with the following option:

```
# chrome binary location specified here
options.binary_location = "/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome"
```

Comment: It says: which: no google-chrome in (/home/bpd/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/home/bpd/usr/local/share)