# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer using Chromedriver on Linux Centos 7 Server

Tags: python, linux, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use headless chrome on a Linux Centos 7 server with selenium and python. I am getting the following error when trying to activate the driver:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "send_notif_marktplaats.py", line 128, in <module>
    main()
  File "send_notif_marktplaats.py", line 117, in main
    driver = activate_driver()
  File "send_notif_marktplaats.py", line 42, in activate_driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver", chrome_options=optionsChrome)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: headless chrome=80.0.3987.116)
```

My versions:

- Chromedriver version 80.0.3987.106
- Google chrome 80.0.3987.116

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Execute chromedriver and chrome to see if you need to install some packages.

Comment: getting this error when executing chrome with sandbox
`[0219/114121.573710:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(308)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly`

Comment: which options did you configure for the chrome browser? Why don't you use version 81? It won't work with version 80.

Comment: I only used no-sandbox right now, but I tried these ones as well:
`optionsChrome.add_argument("--headless")  
optionsChrome.add_argument("start-maximized")  
 optionsChrome.add_argument("disable-infobars")  
 optionsChrome.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
 optionsChrome.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
 optionsChrome.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
 optionsChrome.add_argument("--no-sandbox")`

Comment: I will try version 81

Comment: @ManaliKagathara Why does it not work on version 80?

Comment: only beta version available and it is not supporting it.

Comment: did you fix this problem and how? @Tycho Koster

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: headless chrome=80.0.3987.116)
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver v80.0* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

---

As per the discussion [WebDriver 80.0.3987.16 can't open Chrome on Linux](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3336) `@triciac` updated that, the implementation of [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) **v80.0** looks for *Chrome* in the following order:

1. locations->push_back(base::FilePath("/usr/local/sbin"));
2. locations->push_back(base::FilePath("/usr/local/bin"));
3. locations->push_back(base::FilePath("/usr/sbin"));
4. locations->push_back(base::FilePath("/usr/bin"));
5. locations->push_back(base::FilePath("/sbin"));
6. locations->push_back(base::FilePath("/bin"));
7. locations->push_back(base::FilePath("/opt/google/chrome")); // last try with the default installation location.

`@johnchen`, confirmed that, the binary search order on Linux was accidentally changed by [r708243](https://crrev.com/708243), which was intended to make it easier to configure the name of the Chrome binary, but accidentally changed the search order as well.

*ChromeDriver* team have updated *ChromeDriver* to fix this issue through this [revision](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/424bb8bf09218e7ce1a56a90b379ec34b2f2a65a) / [commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/424bb8bf09218e7ce1a56a90b379ec34b2f2a65a).

---

### Solution

The above mentioned solution is available with:

- [ChromeDriver v80.0.3987.106](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=80.0.3987.106/)
- [ChromeDriver v81.0.4044.20](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=81.0.4044.20/)

---

### Interim solution

An interim solution would be using the `binary_location` **attribute** and you can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium: WebDriverException:Chrome failed to start: crashed as google-chrome is no longer running so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073411/selenium-webdriverexceptionchrome-failed-to-start-crashed-as-google-chrome-is/53078276#53078276)