# Crontab Selenium Chromium in Raspberry pi (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

Tags: python, selenium, raspberry-pi

I'm runing crontab with selenium and chromium.

If I don't run the script with crontab evertithing works fine.

I want to display the the screen on startup but it gives me this error.

```
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so 
 ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

This is my cron:

```
 @reboot DISPLAY=:0 sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/main.py > /home/pi/selenium.log 2>&1
```

My python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

driver = webdriver.Chrome( executable_path="/usr/bin/chromedriver" ,
    service_args= [ "--verbose", "--log-path=/tmp/CHROMIUM_LOG" ],
    options = chrome_options
)
```

I've tried evertithong from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073411/selenium-webdriverexceptionchrome-failed-to-start-crashed-as-google-chrome-is) already.

Also if there is any other way to run the script on stratup and display the browser please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented a lot with this and the only way it worked for me was to set 2 minute timer to start the script.

I changed the crontab to this:

```
@reboot DISPLAY=:0 sleep 120 && sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/main.py > /home/pi/selenium.log 2>&1
```