# Chrome not running without headless mode (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I'm working on a script that scrapes some data from a dynamic webpage and commits it to my database tables. For this, I've used Selenium in Python. It all worked perfectly fine until I restarted my system. Now chrome only works in headless mode and when I comment out that option so that I get to see an actual window of the chrome browser, I get this error

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
>   Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.   (unknown error:
>   DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)   (The process started from
>   chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so
>   ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

[image: snapshot of the code]

Solutions tried:

- cross-checked the path of my chrome-binaries and it is valid
- changed the order of adding options
- uninstalled chrome and reinstalled it again
- deleted the chromedriver and downloaded it again
- restarted my system twice
- googled the error and tried the solutions

EDIT: I have already tried adding the --no-sandbox option before commenting it out here as shown in the snapshot

One thing I would want to mention is that my root space is quite less and only 340 mb of free space is left. Does that affect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see an actual window of the chrome browser removing the argument `-headless` is perfect.

However, I would suggest to remove all the unwanted options and execute your test with the minimal lines of code as follows:

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chrome_options.add_argument('start-maximized')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://google.com/")
```

---

In case you see the error as:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally. (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

You may need to add the argument `--no-sandbox`.

So the solution is to add back the argument:

```
chrome_options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
chrome_options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t/50642913#50642913)

---

### Additional considerations

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v83.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.39/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 83.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v83.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.39/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion in:

- [Selenium: WebDriverException:Chrome failed to start: crashed as google-chrome is no longer running so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073411/selenium-webdriverexceptionchrome-failed-to-start-crashed-as-google-chrome-is/53078276#53078276)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I did try removing --no-sandbox argument and it didn't work

Comment: @HumaidKidwai You need not remove, rather you need to add back.