# Can we run selenium test in non-headless mode in linux?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I knew and it is working fine also with headless mode on linux(python+selenium), for headless mode

```
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(webdriver_manager.chrome.ChromeDriverManager().install(),
                                   chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

**My requirement: Want to run selenium/python script  without headless chrome mode(i.e. non-headless)**
But when i comment or remove line (--headless),

```
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        #chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(webdriver_manager.chrome.ChromeDriverManager().install(),
                                   chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

or even (--no-headless)

```
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(webdriver_manager.chrome.ChromeDriverManager().install(),
                                   chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

it gave me error with above (non-headless) change while running python script,

```
Looking for [chromedriver 84.0.4147.30 linux64] driver in cache
File found in cache by path [/***/drivers/chromedriver/84.0.4147.30/linux64/chromedriver]
Error in UI Test: local variable 'browser' referenced before assignment
```

Can someone help me to achieve this requirement, if possible in linux?

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using `--headless`, ideally you should remove the following argument as well:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
```

Comment: thanks for help but after commenting above line gave error, "Error while testing user interface: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)"
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Comment: @Vinod This is the actual error `The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running`which you need to address. See: [Selenium: WebDriverException:Chrome failed to start: crashed as google-chrome is no longer running so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073411/selenium-webdriverexceptionchrome-failed-to-start-crashed-as-google-chrome-is/53078276#53078276)