# error chrome as crashed when trying to launch selenium chromedriver unix centos7

Tags: linux, selenium, google-chrome, centos, selenium-chromedriver

I have spent hours on this error. tried all the given solutions and still have the following error :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

I have a linux/centos7 - I am using ssh putty to connect the serveur.
I have
google-chrome --version

```
Google Chrome 85.0.4183.102
```

chromedriver -v

```
ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.87
```

Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url='https://www.google.com'
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('–-no-sandbox')
option.add_argument('–-headless')
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option)
driver.get(url)
print(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()
```

I have also tried with

#!/usr/bin/python3.6

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display 
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768)) 
display.start() 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url='https://www.google.com'
driver.get(url)
print(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()
```

and still have the same error. Through ssh I have tried as root and non-root user but still the same..

As information, when doing

google-chrome --no-sandbox : gives :

```
[4463:4463:0919/160950.452059:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1417)] Unable to open X display.
[root@ns344379 mail_from_any_webpage]# [0919/160950.501241:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(308)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
[0919/160950.501399:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(308)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

and I add that I had installed google-chrome successfully but I had an error message while installation :  "Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start atd.service
Failed to start atd.service: Unit not found." (I am under plesk)

```
 Running transaction
  Installation : google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.102-1.x86_64                           1/1
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start atd.service
Failed to start atd.service: Unit not found.
  Vérification : google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.102-1.x86_64                           1/1

Installé :
  google-chrome-stable.x86_64 0:85.0.4183.102-1

Terminé !
```

Comment: already read the last post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073411/selenium-webdriverexceptionchrome-failed-to-start-crashed-as-google-chrome-is

Comment: Do you happen to have X11 installed on the server at all?   `Unable to open X display`?

Comment: Thanks I resolved thanks to this post : WebDriverException: unknown error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t