# Unable to open chromium browser in VPS with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, vps

I need to open chromium or chrome with selenium in Ubuntu 22 deployed in Digital Ocean VPS droplet. The issue is it doesnt open a chrome tab, the chromium and chromedriver are same version.This works fine in my localhost, with ubuntu 22.However, I was not able to run it when deployed in vps

```
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_extension(pluginfile)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)
```

I tried several things including the suggestions here [Selenium: WebDriverException:Chrome failed to start: crashed as google-chrome is no longer running so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073411/selenium-webdriverexceptionchrome-failed-to-start-crashed-as-google-chrome-is)

The error is

```
 (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
 (The process started from chrome location /snap/bin/chromium is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

As I already mentioned, this will work perfectly fine in localhost with same OS and chromedriver and chromium version.

Any idea how to make it work in a VPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempt, I finally found the reason
VPS doesn't allow selenium to open the browser.It only works in `headless` mode, which doesn't fit my requirements since I have plugins and `headless` mode will not run with plugins