# Chrome failed to start in Selenium, the process started from chrome location is no longer running

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to run Selenium in a certain Chrome Profile with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 1')
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), executable_path='/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome', options=options)
browser.get("https://gmail.com")
browser.maximize_window
time.sleep(3)
```

I had to add all

```
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
```

in order to make it work. ([Selenium: WebDriverException:Chrome failed to start: crashed as google-chrome is no longer running so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073411/selenium-webdriverexceptionchrome-failed-to-start-crashed-as-google-chrome-is) first solution)

However, I want to run this script without "--headless" to show the browser without opening.

The error log was:

```
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), executable_path='/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome', options=options)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxxx/Documents/Programming/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxx/filename.py", line 11, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), executable_path='/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome', options=options)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 104, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x0000000104b1fae8 chromedriver + 4958952
1   chromedriver                        0x0000000104b177b3 chromedriver + 4925363
2   chromedriver                        0x00000001046d91d6 chromedriver + 475606
3   chromedriver                        0x000000010470549c chromedriver + 656540
4   chromedriver                        0x0000000104701069 chromedriver + 639081
5   chromedriver                        0x000000010474c6e9 chromedriver + 947945
6   chromedriver                        0x000000010474ba7f chromedriver + 944767
7   chromedriver                        0x00000001047429e3 chromedriver + 907747
8   chromedriver                        0x000000010470caef chromedriver + 686831
9   chromedriver                        0x000000010470e00e chromedriver + 692238
10  chromedriver                        0x0000000104adb9ad chromedriver + 4680109
11  chromedriver                        0x0000000104ae0c12 chromedriver + 4701202
12  chromedriver                        0x0000000104ae779f chromedriver + 4728735
13  chromedriver                        0x0000000104ae1b7a chromedriver + 4705146
14  chromedriver                        0x0000000104ab427e chromedriver + 4518526
15  chromedriver                        0x0000000104b01908 chromedriver + 4835592
16  chromedriver                        0x0000000104b01a87 chromedriver + 4835975
17  chromedriver                        0x0000000104b1100f chromedriver + 4898831
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff81101b259 _pthread_start + 125
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff811016c7b thread_start + 15
```

Thank you for your time!