# Jenkins is failing to find Chrome browser for automated tests - what can I do?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, automated-tests

I'm trying to start to run in Jenkins my tests
java + selenium+ TestNG
for exemple Im try to get title on  google.com
In my IDE all work correct, my code  in git, jenkins starting, compile project
To sure that all correct my simple method print some text, its work
ChromeDriver was started successfully.

but webdriver (chrome driver) get this problem [image issuge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsLqn.png)

Im search issue every were says make sure thats Chrome browser and webdriver version the same. it correct version is the same

Im think  that webdriver can't  find to chrome browswer:

> "The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is
> no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has
> crashed.) "

How can I run test with webdriver   or how to show for webdriver path to Chrome browser?

I will be grateful for any help
Thanks and have a good day!
[stacktrace 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuMKb.png)
[stacktrace 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsLqn.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the version of Chrome and the version of ChromeDriver to your question.

Comment: _SessionNotCreatedException_: Update the question with the complete error stacktrace and the version of Chrome and the version of ChromeDriver.

Comment: Chrome browser - 113.0.5672.92

Comment: Chrome Driver  - 113.0.5672.63

Comment: did you try to run it in headless mode? please see this post, seems like your error is very similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073411/selenium-webdriverexceptionchrome-failed-to-start-crashed-as-google-chrome-is

Answer (score 1):

Great!
Murat Ishen Thank You!
it is works

```
ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
    opt.setBinary("/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable");  //chrome binary location specified here
    
    opt.addArguments("--headless");
    opt.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
```