# chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Here is my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")

sleep(3)
driver.quit()
```

Chrome version is 104.0.5112.102
ChromeDriver version is 104.0.5112.20
Selenium version is 4.10.0

I tried to restart my PyCharm and close all Chrome and restart my PC

Comment: Plz add an error and add any other thing that might help us understand the situation

Answer (score 0):

an error log might be helpful but i think you should specify the path to the chromedriver.exe

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep


chromedriver_path = './chromedriver.exe'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=chromedriver_path)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
sleep(3) driver.quit()
```

`'./chromedriver.exe'` means chromedriver is in the project root folder and you can add options to chromedriver such as

```
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
```

to avoid getting detected as a bot
so it would be like this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep


chromedriver_path = './chromedriver.exe'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=chromedriver_path)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
sleep(3) driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply~
This question has been bothering me all day
Then I realized that the uninstalled high version of Chrome did not remove it for some reason, and the error message was about the path of the high version of Chrome, but I didn't notice it, and I thought the error message was about the path of the low version of Chrome.
There is a high version of Chrome and a low version of Chrome (same path setting as Chrome in Pycharm).
Manually deleted them and it worked!
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you shared,
it looks like you're missing the path of `chromedriver`

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

# Add the path to your chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\chromedriver_win32')
driver.get("http://www.google.com")

sleep(3)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply~ This question has been bothering me all day Then I realized that the uninstalled high version of Chrome did not remove it for some reason, and the error message was about the path of the high version of Chrome, but I didn't notice it, and I thought the error message was about the path of the low version of Chrome. There is a high version of Chrome and a low version of Chrome (same path setting as Chrome in Pycharm). Manually deleted them and it worked! Thanks again!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant chromedriver not Chrome. happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying this?
[Selenium: WebDriverException:Chrome failed to start: crashed as google-chrome is no longer running so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073411/selenium-webdriverexceptionchrome-failed-to-start-crashed-as-google-chrome-is)

code:

````
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
d = webdriver.Chrome('/home/<user>/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
d.get('https://www.google.nl/')```
````

Comment: Thank you for your reply~ This question has been bothering me all day Then I realized that the uninstalled high version of Chrome did not remove it for some reason, and the error message was about the path of the high version of Chrome, but I didn't notice it, and I thought the error message was about the path of the low version of Chrome. There is a high version of Chrome and a low version of Chrome (same path setting as Chrome in Pycharm). Manually deleted them and it worked! Thanks again!