# ChromeDriver run without Chrome installed?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Short question. Is there possibility to run chromedriver and selenium work without chrome app installed?
Thanks

Comment: Short Answer: No

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **No**. You have to have the chrome application inside your computer. However, you do not need t install it. It will work with any portable Chrome versions as well.
You simply have to point to the chrome executable location during tests.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("/path/to/chrome/binary");

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: What do you mean by Chrome Application in the computer but not need to install it? We are trying to use a python program in one of our server that uses Chrome WebDriver but recently the server was restricted not to have any browsers besides the default one, and that removed the Chrome browser and since then we dont see this driver work. How do we address solve this situation please?

Comment: @Ak777, what I meant from this was, you need to have the chrome browser executable inside your server. Installing the browser and having the executable in a folder are two different things. If you have the browser installed, selenium will find the browser automatically. If not, you have to tell Selenium where is the browser executable with above code.